# gwt Menubar issues

Tags: css, gwt, uibinder

What I would like to have is a menu-/navigationbar where I can position most of the elements left and 2 elements on the right. Is it possible to to using a Menubar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a DockLayoutPanel, with each section containing a MenuBar, such as:

```
<g:DockLayoutPanel unit="PX">
  <g:west size="123">
    <g:MenuBar>
      <g:MenuItem>Item 1</g:MenuItem>
      <g:MenuItem>Item 2</g:MenuItem>
      <g:MenuItem>Item 3</g:MenuItem>
      ...
    </g:MenuBar>
  </g:west>
  <g:east size="123">
    <g:MenuBar>
      <g:MenuItem>Item (n-1)</g:MenuItem>
      <g:MenuItem>Item n</g:MenuItem>
    </g:MenuBar>
  </g:east>
  <g:center>
    (You can add anything in between here, including another MenuBar, if desired)
  </g:center>
</g:DockLayoutPanel>
```